# How many calories can the average human absorb in one day?

Tags: body-fat, metabolism, liver, glucose, pancreas

While researching the maximum amount of weight a person can safely lose per week, I came across an interesting factoid that basically stated that the maximum fat reserves that can be processed per day is around 3300 calories, due to how quickly the liver can convert fat into glucose and ketone bodies.

While I won't speak to the veracity of that factoid, it did spur a thought experiment.

I wondered about the inverse: how many calories a person can absorb in a day. If the liver can only convert so much fat into energy, then what are the factors in keeping a person from absorbing energy?

Namely, if a person otherwise ate a normal diet of 2,000 calories a day, with normal energy expenditure, but on a single day consumed say, 6,000 calories worth of food, would they be able to convert the entire 6,000 to fat, or would most of it go "out the back end" so to speak? Would the intestines be able to absorb it quickly enough, and would the liver and pancreas be able to capture it fast enough from the blood stream? Or would it mostly result in a short lived but quite strong glucose spike, followed by the kidneys, pancreas and liver pulling most of it from the blood and dumping it overboard?

So my question is this:

**How many calories can the average human absorb from food in a given day, and what are the limiting factors in this?**

(As an aside, this is just a thought experiment, I'm not suggesting anyone try this)

Comment: Hi stix, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. The problem is extreme athletes also have extreme caloric requirements. I'm more interested in what the body can do with those calories under normal load.

Comment: Fair enough. Now you mention it, I'm reminded of actors who've had to put on weight for a part at short notice. I can't really think of any other occasion it's likely to have come up. Tough to research if there aren't any examples.